# How to change Function0 to the type I want?

Tags: scala

I want to make this block of code to be the type of Supplier, people says using () => { ... } to define a Function0[T] which can be automatically transformed to a Java Supplier, but after I add it below I still got error, can anyone help with this?

```
protectet def helper() {

Decorators.ofSupplier { () => {
            determinationService.callService() match {
                case Success(getTaxResponse) => 
                case Failure(exception) => 
            }
        }
//got error: type mismatch required: Supplier[T_], found: Function0[Unit]

        }.withRetry(getTaxResilience.getDefaultRetryInstance())
            .get()
}
```

edit:
withRety and Decorators.ofSupplier is a function in io.github.resilience4j.decorators;

and scala version is 2.12.14

```
static <T> Decorators.DecorateSupplier<T> ofSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return new Decorators.DecorateSupplier(supplier);
    }
```

```
 public Decorators.DecorateSupplier<T> withRetry(Retry retryContext) {
            this.supplier = Retry.decorateSupplier(retryContext, this.supplier);
            return this;
        }
```

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using?

Comment: I would like to see the definition of `Decorators.ofSupplier`  and on what type is `withRetry` is called on. `Supply` does not have such method. Without the types, I have no clue what your code does.

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using?

Comment: Hi @AlinGabrielArhip, LeviRamsy and Tim, I updated my post, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see. I'm using Scala 2.13.8, and by adding that dependency, your code works by default, except I can't find `getDefaultRetryInstance`, but that's a different story. The idea is that `() => { ... }` is a syntactic sugar for `Function0[T]` which is automatically converted into a Java `Supplier[T]`. For example, this works without additional imports, except for importing `Supplier`:

```
  val mySup: Supplier[String] = () => {
    "done"
  }
  println(mySup.get()) // done
```

So if you can update your Scala version, this should go away on its own.
If not, then you probably have to make this conversion explicit. You can wrap the function `() => { ... }` inside [`asJavaSupplier`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-java8-compat_2.12/latest/index.html), similar to this:

```
  protected def helper(): Unit = {
    Decorators
      .ofSupplier {
        asJavaSupplier { () =>
          {
            determinationService.callService() match {
              case Success(getTaxResponse) => // ...
              case Failure(exception)      => // ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .withRetry(getTaxResilience)
      .get()
  }
```

You'll find the right path from which to import it in the docs. I put the docs for your Scala version in the link. On Scala 2.13, it was moved to a different path, so it makes no sense to show you from where I imported it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `asJava` method of `FunctionConverters` in Scala 2.13 to convert `Function0` to `Supplier`:

```
  import scala.jdk.FunctionConverters._

  val scalaFunc0 = { () => "abc" }
  val javaSupplier: java.util.function.Supplier[String] = scalaFunc0.asJava
```

Comment: This is correct, but incomplete. You can directly use a `Function0` literal in any place a `Supplier` is required, without using `asJava`. For example: `val javaSupplier: Supplier[String] = { () => "abc" }`.